# titanium appcelerator not recognizing certificate on simulator build

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

I'm trying to compile an app with titanium appcelerator.

This is my `run config`

[image]

I got a working apple certificate (also as far as I can see from the documentation - this should be required from a simulator)

When running this config this results in

```
[INFO] :   Alloy compiled in 19.3916s
[INFO] :   Alloy compiler completed successfully
[ERROR] :  Developer Certificate Not Found. Please logout using `appc logout -D` and then re-login again.
```

I also logged out / in without any success

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

So as the error specifies, your developer certificate is invalid. This is NOT the apple certificate, but the Appcelerator one (since you're using the non-open source variant).

So follow instructions and do `appc logout -D`, then after that succeeded do `appc login` and follow instructions. After that all should be good.

Comment: I tried this - but it does not work. I can compile it from terminal without any problems

Comment: have you restarted studio after logout?

Comment: yep I did  ;) also restarted the whole mac